# Class declarations in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I was creating a sample Android project using Kotlin programming language using this [blog](http://cirorizzo.net/2016/03/04/building-a-kotlin-project/). I'm new to Kotlin programming. I came across this line,

`data class Cats(var data: Data? = null)`

which I believe that it is, creating a class named `Cats` that has a variable named `data`. What does this `data: Data? = null` means?  My whole class model is:

```
data class Cats(var data: Data? = null)

data class Data(var images: ArrayList<Image>? = null)

data class Image(var url: String? = "", var id: String? = "", var source_url: String? = "")
```

Comment: You should also read the entire Kotlin language reference along with the blog you mentioned: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/  ... and the concepts you are wondering about are covered there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right that `Cats` class will have a mutable property named `data`, since it is declared inside a primary constructor of a class with `var` keyword (see the docs pages about [classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) and [properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)).

Next, question mark at type name in Kotlin means that a variable has [nullable type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html), that is, it can store `null` value. Variables with not-null types, on the other hand, cannot hold `null`s in Kotlin.

`data: Data? = null` is syntax for [default parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments) value. It allows not to pass `data` parameter to the constructor invocation, and in this case default value `null` will be used. This also works for functions.

And finally, [`data` modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) at class declaration means that `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString`, `copy` and destructuring will be generated for the class, based on the properties declared in primary constructor.

Answer (score 0):

=> Classes in Kotlin are declared using the keyword class:

class Invoice { }

=> Both the header and the body are optional; if the class has no body, curly braces can be omitted.

class Invoice